# Travel to Lithuania with expired residence and confirmation receipt of renewal process in Slovakia

Tags: lithuania

hope you are all doing well.

Currently, I have planned to travel to Lithuania, Kaliningrad, and Gdansk with my Taiwanese passport and residence card in Slovakia.

According to Slovak legislation, the residence is considered valid while waiting for approval of renewal, even after the current residence is expired.

Atm, my current residence is expired from the end of October, and the renewal was started from mid of October. I have the expired card with me, together with the confirmation that I'm waiting for approval.

When checking the document issued by EMN in 2011, I found Lithuanian authorities having vague comments on refusal of exit: https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/networks/european_migration_network/reports/docs/ad-hoc-queries/residence/337._emn_ad_hoc_query_duration_of_stay_and_refusal_of_exit_5aug2011_wider_dissemination_en.pdf

Moreover, I have the e-visa to enter Kaliningrad (for 3 days) and it should be fine to enter Poland if I leave Lithuania with an exit stamp.

I wonder if the residence permit should be under the issuing country law (Slovakia) or under the visiting country law (Lithuania), in case of entry/exit. Tried to search all possible answers but nothing particular for my case.

Thank you all in advance for reading my question and hope to see your comments soon.

Comment: Are you travelling by road or air?

Comment: I will be traveling to Lithuania by air, and leave for Kaliningrad by road.

Comment: I will be traveling to Lithuania by air to VNO airport in Vilnius, and leave for Kaliningrad by road via Nida-Morskoe, which fits the legislation of borders by the e-visa in Kaliningrad. Furthermore, I found the Q&A from European Parliament: http://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/E-8-2015-000886-ASW_EN.html  90 days will start right after the expiry of residence, as proved by them.